# Serializing an object for two different uses in two different formats (should be simple..)

Tags: serialization, c#-4.0

I have an object which is marked as `[Serializable]` and it's properties are marked with `[XmlAttribute]` and `[XmlIgnore]`.It's serialized for our web-site use, and it works well.

Now I need to serialize the same object for a different use (web service), in json format.
I know I can easily serialize objects with the `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes, but I can't use both - `[Serializable]` and `[DataContract]`.

What are my options to serialize the object?
Which is simpler?

Thanks a lot.